# Why does the std::coroutine_handle class provide a static member function rather than a constructor for construting an object?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++20, static-methods, c++-coroutine

In my [`<coroutine>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/coroutine) header I see that `std::coroutine_handle` has, among other things, these two constructors,

```cpp
constexpr coroutine_handle() noexcept { }
                                                   
constexpr coroutine_handle(nullptr_t) noexcept { }
```

and this `static` member function,

```cpp
static coroutine_handle
from_promise(_Promise& __p)
{
  coroutine_handle __self;
  __self._M_fr_ptr
    = __builtin_coro_promise((char*) &__p, __alignof(_Promise), true);
  return __self;
}
```

Now this member `from_promise` can be used to create a `coroutine_handle` with its `_M_fr_ptr` member set to something.

So I'm wondering: why not having the following hypothetical contructor (which, to me, looks like doing the same job) instead of `from_promise`?

```cpp
coroutine_handle(_Promise& __p)
  : _M_fr_ptr{__builtin_coro_promise((char*) &__p, __alignof(_Promise), true)}
{}
```

Given the complexity of the former solution, I assume there's 0% chance that the decision was not important and consciously made.

Comment: I can only guess here but it might be because a constructor conveys the wrong meaning about what this action does.

Comment: @tkausl, what does this action do, other taking an input, constructing an object with it, and returning it? That's what a constructor does as well, no?

Comment: `what does this action do, other taking an input, constructing an object with it, and returning it? That's what a constructor does as well, no?` Well, yes, _kind of_. In this case however one must understand that `from_promise` gives you a handle to __the coroutine which owns that promise__. Just constructing a coroutine handle doesn't convey that meaning.

Comment: "Given the complexity of the former solution" - It's a static member function. I don't think I would describe such a thing as "complexity". "I see no way why my question could ever be opinion based" - Why not? The answer could very well be "In Gor's opinion, this is better."

Comment: That's just the named constructor idiom at work. You also have a `from_address` named constructor too. It's easier to add (and use) named constructors than to untangle overload resolution when regular constructors are added (just count how many standard types need tag dispatch to resolve overloads, that's a hack around a problem if we can be perfectly honest).

Comment: "*why having the latter rather than the following hypothetical contructor, which, to me, looks like doing the same job?*" You mean, besides the fact that it isn't `explicit`? Or besides the fact that it is super-easy to *lie* about whether the object is actually a coroutine promise object?

Comment: @Enlico: "*can be used to create a coroutine_handle from thin air*" Except that it's *not* "from thin air". It's from a pointer to the promise object of a coroutine. If you want some logic for it, you're not creating a *new* `coroutine_handle`; you are getting a copy of a handle that already exists.

Comment: +1 to @NicolBolas - The `from_promise` function is not for constructing a new coroutine handle. It's for *recovering* a coroutine handle from its promise. In other words, the Promise parameter must have originally come from a call to `handle.promise()`, and it returns you the original `handle`.

Comment: @RaymondChen, if the `Promise` I feed to `from_promise` must come from a a call to `handle.promise()`,  how is _that_ handle created in the first place?

Comment: It comes from the compiler's coroutine infrastructure.

Comment: @RaymondChen, then I guess this is what _automatically_ means when Josuttis writes _The promise [...] is automatically created when we start the coroutine_ in his book.

Comment: You can read all about it [in the language specification](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#5). The promise is a local variable in the transformed coroutine body.